# Trace and String Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to test some strings but trace outputs nothing. I was using Flash CS6, then I installed Flash CC then everything was fine. But then I created another loop now the same thing. Here's my code:

```
for (tempNum = lastCharNum; tempNum <= 7; tempNum++) {
    trace(tempNum); // this outputs nothing
    if (arr[tempNum] != String.fromCharCode(9)) {
        firstCharNum = tempNum;
        trace(firstCharNum); // this outputs nothing
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
for (tempNum = lastCharNum; tempNum <= 7; tempNum++) {
    txt.text = String(tempNum); // this doesn't make change to the textfield
    if (arr[tempNum] != String.fromCharCode(9)) {
        firstCharNum = tempNum;
        txt.text = String(firstCharNum); // this doesn't make change to the textfield
    }
}
```

Same thing, nothing happens.

Comment: exactly what line problem? `tempNum`? or `firstCharNum`? or both?

Comment: thank you for your answer. they're both problem.

Comment: Does trace("Some inline string"); work?

Comment: is that in the Flash IDE or outside of the IDE (i.e. in the browser or standalone player) (not getting traces that is)?

Comment: it's in the flash ide. i press ctrl+enter.

Comment: what is the value of lastCharNum?

Comment: the value of lastCharNum is 23

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "Omit Trace Statements" is not checked in the the publish settings. If its not checked, try File>Publish and Control>Test Movie>In Flash Professional to see if you get different results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Control>Test Movie>In Flas Professional is disabled, I can't click on it. In the file menu I couldn't find Publish and Control.

Comment: You need to have an fla open and it needs to be the current document in the editor. If you have a class open and current, it doesn't provide publishing as an option.